# Group elements in a list based on 2 objects, just show the element once if they have the same values and also display the count

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream, grouping

I have a piece of code as below :

```java
List<Locations> locationList = getLocations(locations, eventTypeList, eventIdentityData);
```

This gives me a list of locations.

My **Location.java** class is as below :

```java
private String city;
private String country;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
```

These also have the getters and setters.

So if I get an output like :

```
"locations": [
    {
        "city": "Dubai",
        "country": "United Arab Emirates",
        "latitude": 25.2048493,
        "longitude": 55.2707828
    },
    {
        "city": "Dubai",
        "country": "United Arab Emirates",
        "latitude": 25.2048493,
        "longitude": 55.2707828
    },
    {
        "city": "Delhi",
        "country": "India",
        "latitude": 10.2048493,
        "longitude": 40.2707828
    }
]
```

In the above response, there are 2 elements with the same latitude and longitude value, thus those should be grouped together and should be shown as one element with the count as 2. The output should look like the one shown below :

```
"locations": [
    {
        "city": "Dubai",
        "country": "United Arab Emirates",
        "latitude": 25.2048493,
        "longitude": 55.2707828,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "city": "Delhi",
        "country": "India",
        "latitude": 10.2048493,
        "longitude": 40.2707828,
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I know the one thing that I need to do is declare the count variable in my Location class. Also, this means that I need to do the grouping based on the latitude and longitude values (both of them have to be same for the elements to be grouped together). Can someone help me modify this list as per the output that I need?

Comment: Note that deciding that two floats are equal can be difficult. How close do these coordinates have to be together for two locations to be grouped together?

Comment: They have to be exactly the same for them to be grouped together, as I have to render this data on a map.

Comment: *How* exact? Is `1.2345678` equal to `1.23456789`?

Comment: I just need to check to 7 decimal places. And as I am using the Google Geo API to resolve the addresses (which are nothing but IATA codes for airports), it gives me the value as exactly same whether it is upto 1 decimal point or 100 decimal points. So if I pass "DEL" to be resolved, it gives me the same latitude and longitude every time.

Also lets consider for the time being that they are Strings and I have to manipulate my List, how do I do that?

Comment: Do these locations have an `equals` & `hashCode` implementation? You can use `locations.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))` Otherwise, you’d have to replace `Function.identity()` by `l -> Arrays.asList(l.getCity(), l.getCountry(), l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude())`

Comment: @Holger :Now what this does is give me a Map object, Map<String, Long> with the value as count and the key as a combination of latitude and longitude. If I have to convert it to the way I have asked in the question, how would I be able to do it, like List<Locations> distinctLocations. And this list would also contain a count of the occurrence of those same elements, along with the values of all the objects of that element.

Comment: Your `Location` class has no count field.

Comment: As per my question, I have mentioned that I need to add a count object in my Locations class. And I have already done that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stream to group the Locations by a unique representation of their combined latitude and longitude. Then set the count equal to the size of each group.

```
private static Collection<Location> count(Collection<Location> input) {
    return input.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(locaction -> BigDecimal.valueOf(locaction.getLatitude()).setScale(7, ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString() +
                                                 BigDecimal.valueOf(locaction.getLongitude()).setScale(7, ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString()))
                .values().stream()
                .map(locations -> locations.get(0).setCount(locations.size()))
                .collect(toList());
}
```

Example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Location location1 = new Location("a", "b", 1.23232321, 4.56);
        Location location2 = new Location("c", "d", 1.23232328, 4.56);
        Location location3 = new Location("e", "f", 7.89, 0.12);
        Collection<Location> count = count(Arrays.asList(location1, location2, location3));
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static Collection<Location> count(Collection<Location> input) {
        return input.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(locaction -> BigDecimal.valueOf(locaction.getLatitude()).setScale(7, ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString() +
                                                     BigDecimal.valueOf(locaction.getLongitude()).setScale(7, ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString()))
                    .values().stream()
                    .map(locations -> locations.get(0).setCount(locations.size()))
                    .collect(toList());
    }

    public static class Location implements Serializable {
        private String city;
        private String country;
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;
        private int count;

        public Location(String city, String country, double latitude, double longitude) {
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public Location setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the code which you have given above, with changes like 
Collectors.groupingBy() rather than just groupingBy and Collectors.toList() than just toList. But I get a compilation error :
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R, A> collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)

And if I just use groupingBy, it gives me a compilation error at that point.

Comment: I found the issue with my code, even though it was already mentioned as part of yours. My setter for count was different. This code works perfectly fine for me and does exactly what is required.